# What are Custom Exceptions?

Tags: c#, .net, exception

Does anyone knows?
What are Custom Exceptions in .net?
I search in internet but I didn't fine anything
thank u for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes there are some errors that need to be handled as per user requirements.
Custom exceptions are used for them and they are user defined exceptions.

Answer (score 3):

Custom exceptions are classes that you write that inherit from exception classes already present in the .NET framework. This way, you can have your own, explicitly named, specialized exceptions and have them hooked up like any other exception.